# react-native - this.porps.inGrid is not a function

Tags: foreach, react-native

I'm trying to display a nested array containing numbers. The array has 6 elements (arrays). Each nested array contains 6 further elements/numbers. I'm trying to display each number in a Square component. I've got an error: this.props.inGrid.foreach is not a function.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Square from './Square';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';


export default class Grid extends Component {

  render() {
    const row = [];
    this.props.inGrid.foreach((r, i) => {
      row.push(
        <Square key={i} sqValue={r[i]} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.grid}>
        {row}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

Grid.propTypes = {
  numbers: PropTypes.object
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  grid: {
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.BG_COLOR,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Below is the Square component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';


const Square = ({ sqValue }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.square}>
      <Text>{sqValue}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

Square.propTypes = {
  sqValue: PropTypes.number
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  square: {
    backgroundColor: globalStyles.BAR_COLOR,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: 'red'
  }
});
export default Square;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like `inGrid` isn't actually an array at the time that the render function is running.  I would go up one component to see if there's a chance that the data doesn't exist at the time the Grid component is first created.  For example, if that data is coming from an api and the Grid is being rendered before the data returns.

Edit: 
strike all that...you're calling `foreach` and the function should be called `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're calling:

`this.props.inGrid.foreach`

but the function is actually called `forEach`

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Silly mistake